# Problem with comparing an Array with an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Yes this is homework and I am not looking to cheat, I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong :)  " What exactly do I need to do when I have an "undefined" value?

Write a function compare that accepts an array and an object, and returns true if all the array values are present as object values.
Please Note: MY tutor doesnt want the students to use any fancey shortcuts, like Object.values(object)
This is my code so far:

```
const compare = function (array, object) {
    let i = 0;  
    while(i<array.length){
        for(const key in object){   
            if(array[i] == object[key]) {
                console.log("Array val: "+array[i]  + "  " + "Object val: "+object[key])
                i++
            } 
            else if(array[i] !== object[key]){
                console.log("Array val: "+array[i]  + "  " + "Object val: "+object[key])
                return false
            }
        } 
    }
    return true
}
compare(["one", "two", "three"], { 0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three" }); // => true
compare(["one", "two", "four"], { 0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three" }); // => false
compare(["one", "two"], { foo: "one", bar: "two", baz: "three" }); // => true
compare(["one", "two", "three"], { foo: "one", bar: "two" }); // => false
```

What exactly do I need to do when I have an "undefined" value?

Comment: You're returning false after checking the first key rather than checking all the keys first.

Comment: please learn about indentation, will help you and all the people that are going to read your code

Comment: I am getting correct results until i use the third test case

`compare(["one", "two"], { foo: "one", bar: "two", baz: "three" });`

where I have only two indexes so I will evantually compare
undefined with Three

Comment: Oh I see sorry. OK you're comparing the 1st array item with the 1st object value and the 2nd with the 2nd.  But they don't need to be in the same order right?  You just need to see if it's in any of the values.

Comment: `compare(["one", "two", "three"], { 0: "one", 1: "three", 2: "two" });` returns false because I switched the properties around in the object.

Comment: Object.values(object) can subtract much of the complexity.  That will produce an array of the values of the object.

Comment: Yea, but I am not allowed to use these functions yet.. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way (O(n)):

```
function compare(arr, obj) {
  const set = new Set(Object.values(obj));
  
  return arr.every(v => set.has(v));
}

console.log(compare(["one", "two", "three"], { 0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three" }));// => true
console.log(compare(["one", "two", "four"], { 0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three" }));// => false
console.log(compare(["one", "two"], { foo: "one", bar: "two", baz: "three" }));// => true
console.log(compare(["one", "two", "three"], { foo: "one", bar: "two" }));// => false
```

If you need to do it old school (still O(n)), I recommend this:

```
function compare(arr, obj) {
  const set = {};
  
  for (const key in obj) {
    set[obj[key]] = true; 
  } 
  /* for loop works too
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!set[arr[i]]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  */
  while (arr.length) {
    if (!set[arr.pop()]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}

console.log(compare(["one", "two", "three"], { 0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three" }));// => true
console.log(compare(["one", "two", "four"], { 0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three" }));// => false
console.log(compare(["one", "two"], { foo: "one", bar: "two", baz: "three" }));// => true
console.log(compare(["one", "two", "three"], { foo: "one", bar: "two" }));// => false
```

Comment: Thanks WesleyAC , I guess I will modify my code to set the value of the object in another variable and then compare the indexed value of the array with that variable
If !... etc  I guess thats the best way to do it, thanks a lot !